# What exactly creates the global objects in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, global-variables, v8

I have scoured the internet but have not found the information I have been looking for. The global object "this" and its underlying global objects like console, window, document, etc, where do they come from exactly?

What I mean is, are they simply keywords that are recognized by the V8 compiler? If so can someone give a clear explanation about what they are and what exactly is happening?

Thank you.

Jake

Comment: have you read the mdn docs? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this I doubt `this` comes from anything node specific, probably from javascript

Comment: Yes I have, but it doesn't get to the heart of the answer I'm looking for. I suppose what I don't understand is since these things are built into javascript, what does it mean for something to be "Built into javascript"? What is it built into, exactly? The interpreter? Or in node's case, the compiler?

Answer (score 1):

`console`, `window`, `document`, etc are not related to V8, because they are not parts of JavaScript, or ECMAScript, but are parts of Web JavaScript. They are created by browser web contents.

`d8` shell adds some objects to global, such as `console`, that outputs to standard output and error streams.

They are not keywords, V8 handles them as usual object references or `undefined`.

Comment: Infact, if you write JS in some program (e.g. a test with Jest) and don't specify the platform you are targeting (e.g. Node.js vs browser), a linter (e.g. ESlint) might complain about those globals.

For example, both Node.js and Chrome use V8, but while `console` is a global available in both platforms, `window` and `document` are not. They are browser-only. See here for globals available in Node.js https://nodejs.org/api/globals.html